# Why can't my table cells fit my images on mobile browser?

Tags: html, mobile, html-table

here is the issue I'm running into.

I have a 100% width table that is the grid of a map.
The grid is made of several columns and lines. Every cell hosts an image.
Every image of a column has the same width. And every image of a raw has the same height.
So far, so good...

Everything works like a charm on a desktop.
But on mobile it gets complicated: my cells seem not to have the same height.
For example: all my images of the 1st raw have a 868px height, but there is a padding on some cells (which is different depending the cell).
I added a yellow and green background on the raws that point out this unexpected padding.

Here is the test URL where you can see the problem on mobile: http://jcdecaux.atalanta.fr/plan.php

If anyone can help me... that would be nice.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

And if you precise the images dimensions with the width and height tags? 
If it doesn't work better try to define their with css and the !important attribute.

```
style="width: 100px!important; height: 100px!important;"
```

Otherwise, why do you not using a single image ? you could map it.

Comment: Please, translate your answer into english

Comment: hi Uriil, text below the line of separation is the translation.

Comment: I add the code in the english response to make my answer clearer. Sorry for that.